# Why Windows 10 is not showing me notifications when I connect to my VPN?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, internet-connection, notifications

I've tried setting up PPTP VPN both in Windows 10 settings and using Windows phonebook (.pbk extensions) and whenever I connect to either of them, Windows stops showing me notifications and some apps don't work properly. any idea how I can fix it? I'm running Windows 10 May 2020 update (20H1).

I've tried setting my WiFi to non-metered but that doesn't help. I can't find anywhere to set my VPN as non metered.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you did and which notifications are missing, no answer is possible.

Comment: @harrymc Notifications from Mail app, Xbox app, Twitter app, Facebook Messenger etc. 
I haven't tried anything because I haven't found any related setting in registry, Group policy or Windows settings to fix this problem.

when I turn off my VPN, I will be able to see their notifications again when I get one.
on Xbox app it's different, I can't see when I unlock an achievement, when I get party invite etc. but when I disconnect my VPN and connect directly using my own Internet, I can get all those invites, notifications etc.

Comment: Which VPN and how do you connect to it?

Comment: @harrymc Already explained in my post

Comment: Not enough info, but have it your way.

Comment: @harrymc are you joking? you asked for a specific info and I told you it's in the post already. what other info do you want?